# What is the actual meaning of runs in terms of coin tossing?

Tags: probability

I am not able to understand the concept of runs in terms of coin tossing. As per my question, suppose a coin is tossed x times, then we have to find the expected number of runs.

But, what is a run? Can anybody give a detailed example?

As per the question, the sequence of tosses HHHHTTHTTTHHHTHH has 7 runs. How? I am really not able to understand. I researched and found somewhere that a run is when the previous outcome is different from current, so for this case, how will it apply?

Can somebody please explain in layman terms?

Thanks

Comment: a run is a string of h or t

Comment: so in your case, hhhh, tt, h, ttt, hhh, t, hh are you runs

Comment: A run is a sequence of consecutive H or T that cannot be extended forwards or backwards.

Comment: Why will h and t will be the runs? they are not with the same result? Should not the concept of run apply to more that one value of h/t?

Comment: HTHT has 4 runs (short ones!).

Comment: Runs are very useful. Sometimes (indeed more than sometimes) experimental results are invented, or improved on. Badly done invented data tend to have too many runs. This is easily detected.  But it is possible to cheat well.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:Thanks, this is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the full sequence and cut it at each point where there is a *transition* (next value is different from the previous one). Each part is a run.

```
 HHHHTTHTTTHHHTHH  =>  HHHH TT H TTT HHH T HH   => 7 runs
```

In other words, elaborating on Peter's answer, a run is a maximum-length subsequence of equal values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear now. :)

Answer (score 4):

A run is a sequence of equal outcomes (4 times heads , 7 times tails , etc.), so
 if you have n changes from head to tail or vice versa, you have n+1 runs.

Comment: In the case of HHHHTTHTTTHHHTHH, i can understand that the following will be the cases of runs: HHHH, TT, TTT, HHH, HH. But why H and T will be also in runs? They are not sequences right?

Comment: @user3097157 they are part of the run, not a run themselves unless there is a change directly after H or T

Comment: @Rustyn, Can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: For example in this sequence: HTHHTHTHTHT. The runs are: H,T,HH,T,H,T,H,T,H,T. The runs are the chunks of tails or the chunks of heads right before there's a change.

Comment: A sequence of length 1 is still a sequence, though it is not commonly referred to as a run.